# UIImageView doesn't always tint template image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

**In the case below, there are two UIImageViews with the same settings and the same template image... But one tints the image, and one does not**

I duplicated working `UIImageView` and placed it instead of the other and it worked. This happened to me multiple times and this solution always worked, but I still wonder what could I have done wrong? Can it be an Xcode bug? Did something similar happen to you? I have Xcode 8.1.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: you'll need to make sure that the image you're passing to the UIImageView is a template image. Tinting only reliably works when the image in question is being rendered as a template. Here's how to do it using xcassets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517334/modify-uiimage-renderingmode-from-storyboard-xib-file

Comment: It is rendered as a template if it wasn't It would never tint! But it does in some cases as you can see on the images.

Comment: The default rendering mode for UIImage/UIImageView's is UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. Have you explicitly set the mode of the UIImage to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate in either your xcassets or in code?

Comment: I have one image (that little arrow) and it is set as a Template image in my xcassets. I use it in two UIImageViews with identical settings and one tint it and the other one does not. I created UIImage in code whit this image and checked the mode and it was in fact UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate. I fixed it by duplicating working UIImageView, but I am curious if someone had the same issue, because this is not the first time it happend to me and it is starting to be pretty irritating.

Comment: i have the same problem. even created an UIIimageview and override the imagerenderingmode to always as template but no luck ! i used image on tableview cell. some cells get tint color some dont!! its driving me crazy!! im using Xcode 8.3 maybe it's a bug

Comment: I think so too. When I replace buggy ImageView with copied working one it helps. No luck finding out the cause though :(

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis : Set image rendering mode and set tint color at runtime.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**Easy fix solution:**

[image]

Just add a new runtime attribute which will set the tintColor of the UIImageView to the specified color and ensure the image is tinted.

You will still need to set your image to be rendered as a template image in your Images.xcassets file.

This way you dont need any additional outlets, extensions or lines of code.

**Also take note:**
It will not apply the tintColor in the user defined attribute if the tintColor on the view is the same color, they must be different.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in the LaunchScreen.storyboard. But great that it works in normal storyboard.

Comment: Astonishing, and horrifying, that this works. But work it does. Thanks, David!

Comment: Man, great thanks, I’ve been fighting it for almost 6 hours straight and I forgot to set asset as template...

Comment: Read the last note !!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really resolved the issue. But now I'm wondering, how I'm supposed to explain myself to the next developer? :O

Answer (score 59):

Best solution I found that doesn't require a subclass or another `IBInspectable` attribute:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        tintColorDidChange()
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution that works to fix this issue. The Runtime Attribute fix didn't work for me either and this allowed me to still use the settings in Interface Builder as they were intended. Hoping new version of xCode will fix this bug.

Comment: Not eprouved for now, but it seems to be a very nice solution! It's a well separated piece of code, easily removable when the bug will be fixed.

Comment: Remarkable that this is not marked as the answer.. It's the only thing that works consistently in all of my projects *and* it works on all image views. Great solution, thanks!

Comment: Howesome! I've been struggling with this bug for years. Adding a runtime attribute is very bad for applying a theme to your app. This is the best approach for me, thanks

Comment: actually overriding in extension is not a good approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions

Comment: Thank you!! I was baffled when my icons on iOS 13+ were rendering perfectly, yet in iOS 12, they were all black. This really saved me

Answer (score 27):

The problem stems from the value for tint having no null state (within the Storyboard/Interface Builder UI). In order for Xcode to decide whether a tint should be applied to a `UIImageView` there appears to be an additional test. In Xcode this is apparently done by evaluating the constraints applied to `UIImageView`. As far as I know this test is undocumented.

If you only have a "Spacing to nearest neighbor" constraint on two (or one) sides of your `UIImageView` then the tint is not applied regardless of the value set for `UIImage.renderingMode`.

If you have a "Spacing to nearest neighbor" constraint on three (or all) sides of your `UIImageView` then the tint is applied if the `UIImage.renderingMode` is set to `.alwaysTemplate`.

In a purely Storyboard/Interface Builder approach you set the `UIImage.renderingMode` of an image by adding it to an Asset Catalogue and then changing the "Render As" property of the Image Set to "Template Image".

Comment: but the OP stated that the image came from Catalogue and had the attribute render as template

Comment: and also it looks like the constraints for the images are the same, but one image is tinted and the other one not

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much @richardjsimkins for uncovering this. This is imo a bug in Xcode 9 (why would constraints affect the image rendering mode?). I filled rdar://34279759 http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5005434293321728, and encourage you to dupe so this get fixed quickly.

Comment: This will never cease to amaze me. Typical Apple style kind of bullshit, still in their code for years and no one seems to care. That's not like we have to pay to work with this ... Oh wait

Comment: No way, I literally cannot believe that this fixed it. As soon as I added a constraint to the top/bottom of my image view the tint applied.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis I think most teams would just prefer the artist recolor them manually than it be controlled programmatically. So it doesn't come up very often. This question was asked four years before I hit the problem and found the answer.

Comment: This is one of the oddest bugs, and one which needled me for months - so thank you!

Comment: This is fixed in iOS 13.

Answer (score 22):

Try setting `tintColor` programmatically; it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: 2017 and still strange why is it so.

Comment: Now, mid 2018, and still the same problem. A radar has been filled. :'(

Comment: 2019 and still going strong

Comment: almost 2020 still same

Comment: 2020 and still going strong!

Answer (score 16):

I think there is a bug in UIImageView. If you set a tint color in the storyboard, it doesn't apply that tint even when the asset is set up to render as template.

The workaround is to apply the tint color to the UIImageView's parent view in the storyboard.

Or, set the tintColor to nil and then back again in code by binding the UIImageView to an outlet.

Comment: This was my problem, I was setting the tint color in the IB, changed it to default and now I'm assigning it by code, it seems to work now.

Comment: This, in addition to setting the tint color helped me

Comment: This worked for me also. It's vital that you put the tintColor to default in storyboard and then set it in code.

Comment: 2years later and it's still not fixed

Comment: Setting it to `nil` and back worked for me! How stupid.

Answer (score 6):

use this extension to set UIImageView tintColor from interface builder.

```
extension UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var imageColor: UIColor! {
        set {
            tintColor = newValue
        }
        get {
            tintColor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice extension. By the way, there is not need to use 'super' in either the getter or setter.

Comment: No need to write return as well if there is a single line in get. It can be as simple as 
`get { tintColor }`

Answer (score 5):

Runtime attribute trick did not work for me. I made this class just for fixing this kind of stuff.
You'll just set to this class all the problematic image views.

```
final class TintedImageView: UIImageView {

    // WORKAROUND: Template images are not tinted when set using the Interface Builder.
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let preferredTintColor = tintColor
        tintColor = nil
        tintColor = preferredTintColor
    }

}
```

Comment: I used that code but in a UIImageView extension and it worked for the last year of development work. Then today when creating a new view in IB with an image, I suddenly have an issue with some loop happening and layoutSubviews() called over and over forever. No idea why this is happening but it's something to look out for.

Comment: Thanks , it worked. After 2-3 hours spending this is easy solution.

Comment: All I needed was `tintColor = tintColor` to make this work, no temporary variable necessary

Answer (score 4):

By removing my existing UIImageView and adding a new one my problem was gone. 
Apparently, the situation is that you should add the UIImageView AFTER adding the images to the Assets folder.

Answer (score 4):

Keep default tint colour in storyboard
[image]

and add User defined runtime attribute with your chosen colour
[image]

The storyboard will show the image with default tint but when you run, it will show your selected colour.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it helps as I was banging my head for an hour until I realised something that I still quite don't understand.

I had my view in my .nib file and all the outlets except one (the UIImageView) had a non default tint colour. I tried all the suggested answer but the issue was solved by selecting a default tint colour for changing it after programatically.

[image]

[image]

Might it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with XCode 10.3. It's an XCode bug which seems to be related to adding an image to storyboard before adding it to assets.

What helped me is changing tint color to some random color then changing it back to default.

As a result XCode added `<color key="tintColor" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>` to storyboard XML which was missing before. Although it's added as `colorSpace="custom"` the XCode builder shows it as `default`.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS UIImageView and Tint Color and Template Image**

Rendering Modes:

```
.automatic //depends on context where image is used
.alwaysOriginal // original image
.alwaysTemplate // template image
```

- `tintColor` has effect only on `template image`
- `template image` will change **all** colors(except colors with alpha 0 - transparent color) to selected color and only **Alpha** will be taken into account. It means that multicolor image will be transformed into singlecolor image with different alpha

It means that result image will be colorized into **single** color(tint color) with different alphas. That is why you can not colorize some specific parts of your image

Set image as template:

```
// Programmatic
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

// Xcode
<select image in assets> -> Attributes Inspector -> Render As -> Template Image
```

[image]

Set tint color

```
imageView.tintColor = .red
```

> When you add a template image to a button or image view, you also specify a tint color. The view applies the tint color to every pixel that doesn't have an alpha of 0.0, causing the image's shape to adopt that color. To support different appearances, simply change the tint color. For example, you might apply a dark tint color in light environments and a light tint color in dark environments.

[official doc - Create Tintable Images Using Template Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances)

**Additional notes**

- When you set image as template(and don't set tintColor) - imageview will be colorized into default tint color
- SVG staff

  - fill="#RRGGBBAA" doesn't work, you can use fill-opacity="0-1" instead

[[Xcode and vector image]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70910226/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

As @richardjsimkins mentioned, this does seem to at least in some cases have to do with constraints. In my case I wanted to add an image to the center of the launch screen, since in this case I am not able to set the tintColor programmatically. I had to find a pure Storyboard solution.

I found that the tintColor was not set when centering the image view with constraints, i.e. center horizontally/vertically in safe area, which corresponds to it having no "Spacing to nearest neighbor" constraints.

Instead I added a stack view with constraints to safe area leading/trailing/top/bottom and then embedded the image view in the safe area with alignment center, distribution fill. This resolves to the same positioning as directly centering the imageView in the safe area and this made the tintColor take effect.

I do not like having to resolve to using a stack view to force the tintColor to work, but I think it's a small and fairly clean workaround to the bug.