# tintColor of UIImageView doesn't work with storyboard,but work with code

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uicolor

**Xcode 9 beta 6,iOS 11**

I downloaded a **Instagram** logo which was a **.png** file,and I created a `UIButton` and `UIImageView` in the `Main.storyboard`.The logo image was set as follows:

[image: Set mode]

And I set the `TintColor` of the `UIButton` and the `UIImageView` is `white`,but when I run the project, the color of the image for UIImageView is still black,while white for UIButton.

**imageView setting:**

[image]

[image: black color]

> Why it is black for `imageView` and white for `button` with the same
>   setting of the image? Thanks.

**Additional remarks:**

When I used code to add the subview `imageView`,it worked well.Really werid!
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where you are setting the image for both the `UIButton` and the `UIImageView`?

Comment: @Malik I didn't use code, but  the storyboard. I'm sure that all the settings in the storyboard are correct.  A moment ago ,I found a weird behavior that when I used the code to add the imageView, it works (change to white color). I will give a supplementary description in the question.

Comment: In that case, I'm quite certain that you might be setting the value in a wrong place in story board. Can you add the screen shots for attribute inspector for both `UIButton` and `UIImageView`?

Comment: @Malik I have posted the screen shoot of the imageView setting in the question.You can have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the 'Easy fix solution' here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121425/uiimageview-doesnt-always-tint-template-image :)

Comment: @JensSchwarzer Apple told me that it's was bug,I don't know whether it has been fixed or not.

Comment: @Ringo Sure it seems like a bug. I was just proposing a workaround until it has been fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

Problem still exists in Xcode 9.4.1

Setting desired color for `tintColor` in User Defined Runtime Attributes help me to fix this problem:

[image]

Comment: OK, I don't think that Apple will no longer fix the problem. I don't know why. So many people found the issue. And apple has already known it was an issue.

Comment: Thats so disappointing to have the same bug still with XCode 10.2 =(

Comment: It still happens on iOS 11.x, but works fine on iOS 13.x. Tested with Xcode 11.3.1. I have to set alwaysTemplate and tintColor programmatically

Answer (score 4):

I set global tintColor in AppDelegate.

I was not getting proper tint color on iOS 13 Xcode 11 in dark mode. However, same image tint color appeared correct when set fora bar button.

I resolved it by setting **Render As** property of the image as **Template Image** in images.xcassets. I neither had to remove UIImageView in storyboard nor add again or adding user defined property.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changing the image Global tint color from the storyboard:

[image: Global tint color]

Comment: I have uninstalled the XCode for about 1.5 years, I'm not sure whether your solution works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a problem with story board where if the image view is added before adding the image in xcassets as template, the Tint Color does not take effect (if set in the storyboard). I was able to reproduce the problem. I tried the following and it worked.

- Remove the `UIImageView`
- Create a new `UIImageView`
- Set the image and TintColor

Comment: Thanks,but I removed the `UIImageView` and created a new one,omg,  my problem was still exist. I have found several weird behavior with the Xcode9 beta6.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I didn't pay attention to the fact that you're using Xcode 9. Can't say for sure then since I haven't worked with any of it's beta versions

Comment: Anyhow, thanks.I hope this weird issue will not happen in the released version.

Comment: Apple  told me that this is a known bug.

Comment: I'm not surprised

Comment: And the problem still persists in XCode 9.2, and it's not the Beta version. Did they work on it before releasing the version, even after knowing it ?

Comment: @RaviSisodia I‘m not sure whether Apple has fixed it or not.  I've already submitted the issue to Apple, they just told me it's a known issue. When I had a interview in Apple China last year, I also mentioned it.